# Mule 4.x Sample Example With Standard War File Deployment

Tags: mule

We want to embed mule community edition 4.x is our war file. Is there a sample anywhere showing this. With Mule 3x we used the MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.

UPDATE:
I added the mule repositories to my settings.xml as mentioned in the mule documention. I am referencing 4.1.4 and the different mule jar files I need are available except for the builders. I am trying to initialize the mule with the org.mule.runtime.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextServlet passing in the location of the mule context.

When I look for that class in the mule repositories, the latest version I find is here:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.runtime</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-builders</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-FD.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

and during startup I see some errors in comparability. Does anyone know where in the mule repositories I can find version 4.1.4 of the mule-module-builders atrifact?

Comment: Mule 4 that has been removed. There is mention of a new embedded mode, so it looks like it will be supported but haven't seen any documentation on it yet. See servlet/tomcat: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/mule-4-changes#mule-modules-connectors

Comment: Hi,  any news about this subject, i have the same problem, can you please share with me your solution or any suggestion

Comment: We moved away from Mule, didn't see any activity to support this usage pattern.